# Console with normal Java application/program

Tags: java, console

I have made game in Java, and exported it to a Runnable Jar File. When I was developing in Eclipse I had a console along with my game how to get that console when my game is exported as an Runnable Jar File?
(Do I have to run it as an console application?)
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this https://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml

Comment: `jar` files are by default executed with `javaw.exe` (windowless mode - without console). Consider adding GUI components (Swing maybe, like JTextArea) which would simulate console behaviour.

Comment: if you need to see the console you have to run it from console.
use
    java -jar <application.jar>

Comment: Thank you! Is solved it with the sollution of prasadmadanayake